# impossible to replace the character with gsub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, character-encoding

we import a file and in the file there for special crater at first I try encoding methods and decoding ruby and nothing happens, so I used gsub.
work it moist as the character group `ÃŒÂ©` and `ÃŒÂ¤`
For the rest no problem replaces me.

here method replace

```
def replace_chars(name)

  chars = {
          "Å½"   => 'é',
          "Â"    => "ç",
          "â€˜"  => "ë",
          "â„¢"  => "ô",
          "ÃŒÂ¤" => "ç",
          "ÃŒÂ©" => "é",
          "â€¢"  => "ï"
        }

  puts "before #{name}"
  chars.each do |key,value|
    name.gsub!(key,value)
  end
  puts "after #{name}"
end
```

if I but my method

```
replace_chars('ÃŒÂ¤liver Å½ponime')
```

here puts the output of the method, the first he has not succeeded in changing the word but in the second he has made the change.

output : `after ÃŒç¤liver éponime`

I do not understand why he does not want to take my character `ÃŒÂ¤` and `ÃŒÂ©`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

```
def replace_chars(name)
  chars = {
      "ÃŒÂ¤" => "ç",
      "ÃŒÂ©" => "é",
      "â€¢"  => "ï",
      "â„¢"  => "ô",
      "Å½"   => 'é',
      "â€˜"  => "ë",
      "Â"    => "ç"          
    }
  puts "before #{name}"
  chars.each do |key,value|
    name.gsub!(key,value)
  end
  puts "after #{name}"
end

replace_chars('ÃŒÂ¤liver Å½ponime')
before ÃŒÂ¤liver Å½ponime
after çliver éponime
```

Comment: This is not an answer please actually explain yourself because this looks exactly the same except the order in the `Hash`

Comment: First you need to match number of characters in descending order `ÃŒÂ¤`, Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution that will avoid the need to iterate all the characters and will replace matches. @Prashant4020 is correct that you will need to order the keys in descending length or at least sort them by length before performing this operation as `Â` right now will match and substitute prior to `ÃŒÂ¤`.

```
def replace_chars(name
  chars = {
    "ÃŒÂ¤" => "ç",
    "ÃŒÂ©" => "é",
    "â€¢"  => "ï",
    "â„¢"  => "ô",
    "Å½"   => 'é',
    "â€˜"  => "ë",
    "Â"    => "ç"
 }
  #name.gsub!(/#{chars.keys.join('|')}/,chars)
  #as suggested by @steenslag Regexp::union is definitely less of a hack
  name.gsub!(Regexp.union(chars.keys),chars) 
  #translates to name.gsub!(/ÃŒÂ¤|ÃŒÂ©"|â€¢|â„¢|Å½|â€˜|Â/,{"ÃŒÂ¤" => "ç","ÃŒÂ©"=>"é","â€¢"=>"ï","â„¢"=>"ô","Å½"=>'é',"â€˜"=>"ë","Â"=>"ç"})
end
```

This creates a regex that will match the keys from the `chars` hash and then use the values to substitute the keys. This way `gsub!` will not be called for keys that do not exist in the `name` at all.

Comment: `name.gsub!( Regexp.union(chars.keys), chars)` is less hackish.

Comment: @steenslag Thank you. I don't use the actual `Regexp` class often so I was unaware of this method. Updated my post.